# Portable virtual machine with preinstalled Ubuntu for Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualization, qemu

I download "Damn Small Linux (DSL)" distribution from (http://ftp.belnet.be/packages/damnsmalllinux/current/dsl-4.4.10-embedded.zip) and this distribution has a very interesting version called "Embedded" that has QEMU with a DSL virtualmachine already setup and ready to use by just running a simple `.bat` file in Windows just like an application.

So I was wondering, is there any QEMU ready setup with an Ubuntu virtual machine ready to use? I don't want to install anything because I want it on my office PC as an application that I can run and play with.

I know the existence of WUBI, VirtualBox, VMWare, but again, I don't want to install anything, I'm looking for the same behavior as the DSL Embeded but running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can create a Live-USB using [LinuxLiveUSB-Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) which includes a ready-to-run portable Virtualbox for Windows to immediate use the Live Ubuntu.

- No installation is required (well, except for the USB creator program :)
- Virtualbox is better supported, easier to use and has more features than qemu *on Windows*
- You can always copy the contents of the LiveUSB to your hard-disk for a more permanent/faster Virtual Live-Ubuntu

Comment: sounds a really great solution, let me give it a try :D